# R: Problem with NaNs in gamma regression using glm

Tags: r, regression, self-study, generalized-linear-model

I have  found a problem with `NaN`s when I try to fit the model from example 5.1 in the book *Generalized Linear Models. With Applications to Engineering and Life Sciences*. The authors fit a `glm` with gamma distribution and a log link to a dataset about resisitivity (y) and 4 predictors (x1..x4). First, they use a full model: `y ~ x1*x2*x3*x4` and then remove the non significant interactions to arrive to the final model: `y ~ x1+x2 +x3 +x4 + x1*x3 + x2*x3 + x3*x4`.

When I try to replicate the full model with R (they use SAS) I get a warning:
`dgamma(y, 1/disp, scale = mu * disp, log = TRUE) NaNs produced` and in the `summary(model)` the `st.err` and next ones columns are with `NA`s. Therefore, the significance of coefficients is lost.

```
x1 <- c(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1)
x2 <- c(-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1)
x3 <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1)
x4 <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
y  <- c(193.4,247.6,168.2,205,303.4,339.9,226.3,208.3,
        220,256.4,165.7,203.5,285,268,169.1,208.5)

res <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, y)
mod <- glm(y ~ x1*x2*x3*x4, family=Gamma(link="log"), data=res)
summary(mod)

Deviance Residuals: 
 [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  5.26476         NA      NA       NA
x1           0.24705         NA      NA       NA
.
.
.
x1:x2:x3:x4  0.36586         NA      NA       NA

(Dispersion parameter for Gamma family taken to be NaN)
```

Is there some way to circumvent this problem? When I fit the final model: `y ~ x1+x2+x3+x4 + x1*x3 + x2*x3 + x3*x4` the results are exactly the same than in the book.

So, why SAS can resolve the full model and R returns errors?

Comment: Hint: how many parameters are you trying to fit compared to the amount of data you have?

Comment: Yes, the full model has 11 parameters. But SAS can fit it without problems

Comment: That's not the model used in the example. In my copy (example 5.1 is on page 220ff), they say "The initial
model chosen is the main-effects plus two-factor interaction model." That means you should have `glm(y ~ x1*x2 + x1*x3 + x1*x4 + x2*x3 + x2*x4 + x3*x4, family = Gamma(link = "log"), data = res)`. The model in your code has all possible interactions resulting in 16 parameters, not 11. However, the intended model in **R** gives slightly different standard errors that those reported by **SAS** (and found in the book).

Comment: Thanks a lot smilling. You are absolutly right. I was obsesed with the Nans and didn't review the text on page 220. I replied to @whuber from my mobile. Effectivly the parameteres are 16  and that must be the reason of Nans. It's true that the standard errors are higher in R than SAS and so the significances are lower. I have to investigate which are more convenient. Thanks again for your insight.